# TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include

Tags: django

First off I apologize for asking this question again as apparently others have. I am having trouble with this and have been receiving the error that you see in the title of the post.

I'm following along with the tutorial and have understood it up to this point. I'm not even really sure what the method does. So first off if someone can answer that it would be appreciated.

Secondly, how do I fix that error. I realize I must have Django's old syntax. How would I fix that?

**views.py**(I created this file under my root directory)

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(requests):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

**urls.py** (also under root directory)

```
urlpatterns = {
    url(r'^$', 'post.views.index'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)
```

I have an html file called index is in my template/layout

Thanks to anyone who might be able to help. I realize this is probably a total noob question.

Comment: If your tutorial tells you to use a string `'post.views.index'` then it is at least a couple of years out of date and you should look for a different tutorial. The [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/) guides you through creating a polls app and adding the correct url patterns. I recommend working through that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import your post views in the root urls

```
from post import views as post_views
```

Then use the callable `post_views.index` instead of the string `'post.views.index'`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', post_views.index),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

Note that `urlpatterns` should be a list `[url(...), url(...), ...]`. It looks like you might have a set you have a set `{url(...), url(...), ...}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it worked!